API does not return the same data as the object actually holds
I am developing an API using C# where the user can get an estimate on Cloud Cost of that specific Compute Instance.
I am returning a Dictionary of the type Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CloudProduct>> where the first string is "aws", the second string is "onDemand", "1Y", "3Y" and "Storage".
It looks something like this:
{
  "aws": {
    "OnDemand": {
      "cpu": 2,
      "ram": 4
    },
    "1Y": {
      "cpu": 2,
      "ram": 4
    },
    "3Y": {
      "cpu": 2,
      "ram": 4
    },
    "storage": {
      "capacity": "200"
    }
  }
}

In this dictionary there are the classes ComputeOffer and Storage. Both classes inherit from the class CloudProduct.
This is the code returning the data:
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getRequest(CloudCalculationRequest ccr){

    if(ccr.RequestedProviders.Contains("aws")){
        foreach(CloudProduct cloudProduct in ccr.CloudProducts){
            AWSCaldulator.AddCosts(cloudProduct, ccr.PurchaseOption);
        }
    }
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult(ccr); 
    return result;
}

Using a debugger, I can see that up to the last moment when it returns result, data is correct and the classes are recognized correctly:

However, everything the user receives is:
"providers": {
        "aws": {
          "OnDemand": {
            "description": "",
            "name": "",
            "location": "string"
          },
          "1Y": {
            "description": "",
            "name": "",
            "location": "string"
          },
          "3Y": {
            "description": "",
            "name": "",
            "location": "string"
          },
          "storage": {
            "description": "",
            "name": "",
            "location": ""
          }
        }

Those are the only parameters of the CloudProduct class which the Storage and ComputeOffer inherit from.
I think it is because the Framework expects a CloudProduct instance and then uses the default values instead of the actual data.

Do you have public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CloudProduct>> providers { get; set; } in CloudCalculationRequest?  How about replacing it with public Dictionary<string, CloudProduct> aws { get; set; } if you do have it?

You didn't share what is CloudCalculationRequest, CloudProduct, ComputeOffer, Storage and AWSCaldulator.AddCosts, so that I can only write a sample based on my assumption. I'm afraid you got mixed about the data type. Here's my code and test result.
[HttpPost("PcCost")]
public JsonResult getRequest(CloudCalculationRequest ccr)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, CloudProduct> {
        { "OnDemand", new ComputeOffer{ cpu = "2", ram = "4"} },
        { "1Y", new ComputeOffer{ cpu = "2", ram = "4"} },
        { "3Y", new ComputeOffer{ cpu = "2", ram = "4"} },
        { "storage", new Storage{ capacity = "200"} }
    };
    var aws = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CloudProduct>>
    {
        { "aws", dict}
    };

    ccr.aws = aws;
    ccr.aws2 = dict;
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult(ccr);
    return result;
}

public class CloudCalculationRequest {
    public string RequestedProviders { get; set; }//.Contains() so that this might be string
    public List<CloudProduct> CloudProducts { get; set; }//suitable for foreach so that it shall be a List
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CloudProduct>> aws { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, CloudProduct> aws2 { get; set; }
}

public class CloudProduct {
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}

public class ComputeOffer : CloudProduct {
    public string cpu { get; set; }
    public string ram { get; set; }
}

public class Storage : CloudProduct
{
    public string capacity { get; set; }
}

Then I test with input parameter like
{
  "RequestedProviders":"aws",
  "CloudProducts":[
    {
      "description": "desc1",
      "name": "name1",
      "location": "loca1"
    },
    {
      "description": "desc2",
      "name": "name2",
      "location": "loca2"
    }
  ],
  "aws":{},
  "aws2":{}
}

and my API response looks like screenshot below.
{
    "requestedProviders": "aws",
    "cloudProducts": [
        {
            "description": "desc1",
            "name": "name1",
            "location": "loca1"
        },
        {
            "description": "desc2",
            "name": "name2",
            "location": "loca2"
        }
    ],
    "aws": {
        "aws": {
            "OnDemand": {
                "cpu": "2",
                "ram": "4",
                "description": null,
                "name": null,
                "location": null
            },
            "1Y": {
                "cpu": "2",
                "ram": "4",
                "description": null,
                "name": null,
                "location": null
            },
            "3Y": {
                "cpu": "2",
                "ram": "4",
                "description": null,
                "name": null,
                "location": null
            },
            "storage": {
                "capacity": "200",
                "description": null,
                "name": null,
                "location": null
            }
        }
    },
    "aws2": {
        "OnDemand": {
            "cpu": "2",
            "ram": "4",
            "description": null,
            "name": null,
            "location": null
        },
        "1Y": {
            "cpu": "2",
            "ram": "4",
            "description": null,
            "name": null,
            "location": null
        },
        "3Y": {
            "cpu": "2",
            "ram": "4",
            "description": null,
            "name": null,
            "location": null
        },
        "storage": {
            "capacity": "200",
            "description": null,
            "name": null,
            "location": null
        }
    }
}


Just like you see, if we define public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, CloudProduct>> aws { get; set; } in CloudCalculationRequest then we would have providers out of aws. And if we define new Dictionary<string, CloudProduct> but use new ComputeOffer and new Storage inside the Dictionary, the properties in CloudProduct will also be returned.
